# How do you make a file browser list box thing?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm kinda new to c#, and have a large problem...
How do you make something like this in c#? It is like a listbox, but with more stuff than that.

[image]

Like with being able to sort by name, and being able to put different things in like date modified, etc?

I need all the help I can get, like if there is a tutorial, or something else I can get, like dotnetbar, etc.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Object listView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), it's cool and exactly what you needed.

Comment: I'm getting a problem. When I put that in, it is giving me errors, it says this: http://prntscr.com/2gws8y

Comment: I have always been able to put something in like: using such and such. This time there is nothing, what is wrong?

Comment: I can't help you,read documentation carefully. And make sure you download the .dll file and add refence to it from your project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx